# JavaScript. How to implement an array of the last 5 search querie?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, search, redux

I build React-Redux app with Searh by the citys name

[image]

Under the input field i needed to see last 5 cities i’ve looked for. 
To do this, I create an array of the all entered cities and through props, Ill forward them to the component and using `Array.from(new Set(props.arr))` and `.slice(-5)` to create a new arr.

```
import React from 'react';
```

.....

```
function SearchedCitys(props) {

  const uniqueSet = Array.from(new Set(props.citys));
  const citys = uniqueSet.slice(-5);

return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="searched-citys-container">
        {citys.map((city) => (
          <City city={city} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

.......

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchedCitys);
```

There is an bug in this method, when I re-enter the old values ​​that were dropped from the new array of 5 items, they do not repeat again. What a convenient way to filter the source array to display the last 5 searched items?

[LIVE sniped](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-sun-jfvck?file=/src/components/SearchedCitys/SearchedCitys.js)

Comment: can you show how you update `props.citys` in parent

Comment: Would you post live-snippet reproducing your problem? In general, your approach seems to be viable.

Comment: Here are the live sniped:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-sun-jfvck?file=/src/components/SearchedCitys/SearchedCitys.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of actually deriving the cities while rendering, you can actually update your reducer to only have 5 cities

```
case actionTypes.GET_WEATHER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
        loading: false,
        currentWeather: action.payload.currentWeather,
        forecast: action.payload.forecast,
        citys: [
          ...new Set(state.citys.concat(action.payload.city.payload))
        ].slice(-5)
      };
```

The reason you face problem in your solution is because while creating a `Set` it uses the first instance of the duplicate value and since its before the last 5 elements its not being used at all

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-hooks-yko3g?file=/src/store/reducers/reducer.js:370-699)

Comment: Hi, this is perfect solution for me. Thenk you!

Answer (score 1):

it's because you're using a set.

here's what's happening, let's say you typed 6 cities:

```
props.cities = [ a , b , c , d , e , f ]
uniqueSet = [ a , b , c , d , e , f ]
citys = [ b , c , d , e , f ]
```

now when you add another "a", your "uniqueSet" will keep the first a, that's why it won't be on the end of your sliced array.

so what you need to do is :

on your reducer, add the the new city on the start of your array:

```js
case actionTypes.ADD_SEARCHED_CITY:
    return {
    ...state,
      citys: [action.payload,...state.citys],
      };
```

and on your searchCities component :

```
function SearchedCitys(props) {
  const r = props.citys
  const uniqueSet = Array.from(new Set(r));
  const citys = uniqueSet.slice(0,5)


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="searched-citys-container">
        {citys.map(city => (
          <City key={uuidv4()} city={city} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

if you want to show the last added city on the right, just reverse the sliced array

```js
  const citys = uniqueSet.slice(0,5).reverse()
```